# Is there a politically correct term for illiterate people?

Tags: politeness, euphemisms, political-correctness

The question says it all. What is the standard, compassionate/politically-correct term for those who lack a literacy education?

I'm looking for something a little higher in register and more accurate than "reading-challenged" or similar.

Comment: My first feel is that since the very concept it refers to is negative, a good euphemism would have to be invented for the concept (see "differently abled" or "intellectually challenged"), and with the low prevalence of literacy, this is unlikely to occur.

Comment: Oral cultured? Oral minded? Oral based?

Comment: 'Educationally deprived' seems to sum it up in a nutshell. Of course, there is a variety of reasons that people may be unable to read, some of which are societal; some medical/developmental; some individual; and some due to a combination of factors. Plus, of course, there are people who do not read because they belong to pre-literate societies, such as most of the tribespeople living in the Amazon whose languages have never existed in written form (at least till relatively recently).

Comment: Illiterate is politically correct already.

Comment: _Literary challenged_ can encompass all aspects of literacy problems.

Comment: If it really needs softening perhaps: 'poor reading skills'?

Comment: I'm with @BlessedGeek on this: *illiterate* is already clinical, descriptive, and judgment-free. Any other term one could come up with would have to somehow have to provide a *reason* for their illiteracy, which smacks of *excusing* them, which implies a *norm* that one *ought* to be literate, which is antithetical to the objectives of politically correct speech. With all that said: choose whatever term you please, just make you only use it in *written* form. :)

Comment: Plus, don't forget, most of the people in the world are in fact illiterate; and many of the languages they speak have little or no or very, very different traditions of literacy than the Anglophone world. And at that, Anglophone literacy rates are nothing to write home about. Becoming literate in Japanese for a native speaker, for instance, requires from five to ten times the time and effort as becoming literate in English for a native speaker.

Comment: @JohnLawler, Why is it harder to become literate in Japanese than English? Simply because of the difference between ideographic and alphabetic orthography? Do you know of any articles on this topic for the interested layman?

Comment: Take a look at Crystal's _Cambridge Encyclopedia of Language_, or the chapter on Japanese in Sampson's _Writing Systems_. The basic problem is that Japanese writing was designed by bored courtiers with art, obfuscation, and irony in mind, and way too much time on their hands. Not only does it require learning one alphabet and two syllabaries, plus the usual Arabic numerals, but also uses variants of Chinese characters, most of which have been borrowed more than once, at different stages of language development, and thus have several different pronunciations and meanings.

Comment: I suppose if you told someone they were illiterate, they could be offended, but if it's written down they wouldn't know anyway. (Boyfriend's joke which made me lolled!)

Comment: Literacy-challenged is probably not a good choice makes it sound like the person is retarded/mentally challenged which is not necessarily true. Many people are illiterate merely because they haven't had the opportunity to go to school and so their literacy level really isn't an accurate representation of their intellectual capabilities.

Comment: We don't say literacy education. We say learning reading and writing.

Comment: @Lambie in my daughter's school (UK, serves ages 4-11, and not unique in this) "literacy" *is* used as a subject name to include spellings and the reading/writing exercises that aren't part of another subject. In general they seem to be exposed to a lot of technical terminology and jargon these days

Comment: @ChrisH Whenever I hear or read anyone banging on about "the three Rs" I always think "Do you mean literacy and numeracy?"

Comment: @DanBron How about non-literate? I would say that it implies that there has been no attempt to teach literacy to the person being discussed whereas "illiterate" implies that attempts have been made to teach them but that the attempts have failed. To me slaves in the US before the civil war would have been non-literate because it was illegal to educate them but people from the city ghettoes of modern cities who can't read would be illiterate because some attempt (however inadequate) has been made to teach them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My impression from a quick Google Books search is that the term *nonreaders* has often been used in recent years as a neutral way to identify persons who cannot read.

From Ronald Farrar, [*Mass Communication: An Introduction to the Field*](https://books.google.com/books?id=SyxZhSSHS0UC&q=%22nonreaders%22&dq=%22nonreaders%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=yAahVNKvFcjMoASOk4H4Bw&ved=0CEMQ6AEwCA) (1995) [snippet not visible in box]:

> Catch phrases often used by **nonreaders** include: "I forgot my glasses." "I can't read that print." "I'll read it when I get home." "You read it for me." "I can't understand those big words." In questioning persons

From Sam Weintraub, [*Annual Summary of Investigations Relating to Reading, July 1, 1995 to June 30, 1996*](https://books.google.com/books?id=QW0ZAQAAIAAJ&q=%2276+nonreaders%22&dq=%2276+nonreaders%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=hQahVO-gE5awogTr8IDACQ&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAA) (1997) [combined snippets]:

> Using the results of the word identification test, the subjects were divided into 2 groups: 76 **nonreaders**, who could not identify any words, and 20 novice readers, who could identify 1 or more words. Anova and ancova procedures were applied to explore differences between **nonreaders** and novice readers on the various indices of phonological sensitivity.

From Judy Richardson & Raymond Fagan, [*Reading to Learn in the Content Areas*](https://books.google.com/books?id=hXYKAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA347&dq=%22can+barely+read+or+who++is+a+nonreader%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=HKShVMXmD8K2oQSg8oGICQ&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22can%20barely%20read%20or%20who%20%20is%20a%20nonreader%22&f=false), volume 1 (2003):

> What can the content-area teacher do with the student who can barely read or who is a **nonreader**? The teacher can (1) pretend such a student is really not that bad a reader and do nothing, (2) get help from a reading specialist, or (3) assign extra work to help a student in this situation. Ideally, content area teachers do both (2) and (3).

Unfortunately for people who like to use language unambiguously, the term *nonreaders* is also sometimes used to identify people who simply don't choose to read a particular periodical or form of content (as in "nonreaders of newspapers") or to people who dislike reading despite knowing how. So  *illiterate* is arguably a clearer term than *nonreader* for indicating the inability to read. But as discussed below, *illiterate* isn't an altogether unambiguous word either.

The point of euphemistic speech is to avoid using words that some hearers might find vulgar, offensive, or otherwise unpleasant—and it can hardly be denied that, in a society that prizes literacy, *illiterate* has negative connotations. Indeed, for hundreds of years, writers have often used it as part of extended insults, which is how pejorative senses of objectively neutral words gain their teeth. For example, from Samuel Low, [*The Politician Outwitted, a Comedy*](https://books.google.com/books?id=ENkQAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA365&dq=%22you+illiterate%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=xqahVPhuxeegBPSqgaAG&ved=0CEcQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=%22you%20illiterate%22&f=false) (1789):

> HUMPHREY. A boar! why you're worser than he there—he only took father's *corn* for *pigs*, but do you take me for a *boar*, eigh? Do I look like a *hog*, as the saying is?
>
> FRANKTON. Begone, you **illiterate** lubber!—My dear Charles, I have a thousand things to say to you, and this is an unfit place for conversation.

This instance is especially interesting because it illustrates the ambiguity of the word *illiterate* when used in a nonclinical sense. In fact, the Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary (2003) identifies several definitions of *illiterate*:

> **illiterate** *adj* (15c) **1 :** having little or no education; *esp* : unable to read or write {an illiterate population} **2 a :** showing or marked by a lack of familiarity with language and literature {an *illiterate* magazine} **b :** violating approved patterns of speaking or writing **3 :** showing or marked by a lack of acquaintance of a particular field of knowledge {musically *illiterate*}

Frankton's criticism of Humphrey in *The Politician Outwitted* might, therefore, be that he is generally uneducated, that he can't read or write (or both), that he doesn't show any taste for literature, or that he violates approved patterns of speaking.

From "[Back Talk](https://books.google.com/books?id=JNsjAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA88&dq=%22you+illiterate%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=xqahVPhuxeegBPSqgaAG&ved=0CEIQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=%22you%20illiterate%22&f=false)" in *The Adjustor* (September 1914):

> That settles this phase of the financial situation pretty well, I should say, but out here on the coast we are principally interested in being informed why ... is the price of eggs being boosted to the neighborhood of 50 cents per dozen, and restaurant roast beef being sliced so thin that it is impossible to stick a fork into it? Answer me that, you **illiterate**, mouthing apology for a hiccoughing Washoe canary, and then go back to your manger and eat some more hay.

From Keith Peterson, [*The Trapdoor*](https://books.google.com/books?id=acUto9-sZycC&q=%22you+illiterate%22&dq=%22you+illiterate%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=862hVMiNBJCSoQTx9YCwAg&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAA) (1989) [snippet]:

> Then the editor got the "message" signal on his screen and he pressed a button and the words, "[From Wells] You suck, you **illiterate** scum!" appeared right before him. Or something very much like.

Somehow, "You nonreader!" seems fangless in comparison to "You illiterate!" But if *nonreader* becomes sufficiently associated in the popular imagination with the underlying notion of illiteracy, it is likely to acquire pejorative connotations itself, and its usefulness as a euphemism will come to an end. At any rate, that seems to be what happened with *retarded* as a euphemism for "having unusually low mental capacity."

Comment: I know lots of nonreaders none of whom is illiterate.

Answer (score 9):

Illiterate is the right term. The important thing is to use it in a neutral way and not write as if illiteracy deminishes a person's value or innate intelligence.

"Low literacy" is also a really good term because literacy is a continuum ranging from very very basic to very proficient. Referring to literacy as having levels is therefore more accurate than saying everyone is either literature or illiterate. Especially since people's levels of literacy can change throughout life.

For example, a woman who can read a few sentences, but not a bus schedule or a tax form. She isn't entirely illiterate, but she's also not literate enough to function in a highly literate society (e.g. North America). So saying that she has a basic level of literacy acknowledges the abilities she does have.

This is the sort of terminology used by the [National Assessment of Adult Literacy (NAAL)](http://nces.ed.gov/naal/kf_demographics.asp).

Comment: Absolutely right.

Answer (score 4):

You might find that "[*functionally* illiterate](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_illiteracy)" (wikipedia) is a better fit to what you mean. It refers to having the skills to use written language beyond the most basic level (another answer had the example of a bus timetable, IMO the tax form example is usually a level higher still). The addition of a specific and technical modifier also removes the ambiguity you allude to where "illiterate" can be read as an insult rather than a factual description. This could also be done as a matter of context of course.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the abundant misusage of the term 'illiterate' (as a deriding word), I think it is hard to use it without sounding condescending/insulting. How about using "uneducated" or "unschooled" instead? However, the exact meaning of these terms, too, can be vague. Hence, I would say the best way to address this group is by using an entire phrase, instead of a single term, to indicate what you exactly mean.

Comment: Welcome to [ELU.SE] @Kashyap. 
We're looking for answers with [more detail](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).
Your post would be improved if it included a reference and an explanation of why it answers the question.

Comment: Unschooled unfortunately currently has connotations to the [unschooling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unschooling) movement.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably go with **[unlettered](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/unlettered)**, an old-fashioned but still readily-understandable English word that literally means illiterate, but will be taken as quite polite, perhaps even quaint. Google Ngrams claims the word is [still being used](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=unlettered&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cunlettered%3B%2Cc0) but slowly fading out.

Comment: Are the more recent appearances referring to illiteracy or to the absence of letters?

Comment: Scanning through at least some of the recent corpus, they seem about equally split three ways: illiterate, unschooled, and lacking lettering.  There are definitely still recent uses of it to mean illiterate, e.g. https://books.google.com/books?id=TIuwAAAAIAAJ&q=%22unlettered%22&dq=%22unlettered%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ao-jVPO4H4eVNrCvgHA&ved=0CEgQ6AEwCQ

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use the term "non-literate", as it doesn't seem to have the same negative connotation as "illiterate" but at the same time feels judgement free.